# HTML tables displaying data at the bottom

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two tables placed side by side under one div element. However, the number of items in each table are different. The data in the lesser table is placed at the bottom and not at the top. I want data to start from the top and proceed downwards.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Baseline/HD diffs</label>
   <div class="col-md-7 container table-responsive">
  {% if item.baseline_diff %}
  <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="inlineTable" style = "font-size:11px;">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th scope="col">Baseline</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     {% for d in item.baseline_diff %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{ d }}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
  </table>
  {% endif %}
  {% if item.hd_diff %}
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="inlineTable" style = "font-size:11px;">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th scope="col">HD</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     {% for d in item.hd_diff %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{ d }}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
  </table>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#inlineTable {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 40%;
       }
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: not a screenshot but the final generated code

Comment: I have the screenshot. How do you want me to put the source code? Its part of a modal and many other ajax calls. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And now i saw that you have same id at two tables  id must be unique

Comment: I will rectify that and add the CSS separately for each. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In the future, adding a demo/fiddle/pen/etc. will expedite resolution and be more helpful to others that have a similar (or same) issue and find this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `vertical-align`

```
#inlineTable {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/su9de3zt/